# How to extract total values in a dynamic html with python?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, dynamic, python-requests

I could extract part of the values I need in the html, but I am unable to extract all the values. How could I  get values completely in python ?

```
import time
import requests
!pip install beautifulsoup4
import bs4
!pip install lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}

output =[]

url = "https://m.pcone.com.tw/store/0670386?ref=d_item_store"
       
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")



for product in soup.find_all("a",class_='product-list-item'):
    
    productname = product.find("div",class_='name limit-2-line').get_text(strip=True)
    productprice= product.select_one("span",class_='symbol-price').string

    ordercount = product.find('span',class_="order_count").string[:-3] if product.find('span',class_="order_count")else None
    print(f'{productname}:{productprice}:{ordercount}')
    output.append([productname, productprice, ordercount])

  
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['商品名稱', '價格', '購買人數'])
df.to_excel('松果-瑞昌.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, data is loaded dynamically by javascript from api calls json response that's why BeautifulSoup can't grab data. The minimal working solution from api using only requests as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}

params={
    'items_per_page': '20',
    'null':'' ,
    'page': '1',
    'sortBy': 'default',
    'sortDir': 'desc',
    'store_id': '0670386'
}
output =[]

#url = "https://m.pcone.com.tw/store/0670386?ref=d_item_store"

api_url='https://www.pcone.com.tw/api/filterSearchTP'

for i in range(1,14):
    params['total_pages'] = i    
    resp = requests.get(api_url, headers = headers,params=params).json()
    for item in resp['products']:
        productname=item['name']
        productprice=item['msrp']
        ordercount=item['order_count']
        #print(ordercount)

        output.append([productname, productprice, ordercount])

  
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['商品名稱', '價格', '購買人數'])
df.to_excel('松果-瑞昌.xlsx', index=False)
```